# Bluetooth tool to send bytes to my smartphone

Tags: android

I'd like to test my Bluetooth App and for this reason I'm looking for a program that allows me to send some CAN Messages or some bytes. Does anyone have such a program?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have a bluetooth capability on your computer?  Which of the sub-protocols do your computer and phone both handle?

Comment: I have bluetooth stick from BlueSoleil and using it as a Seriell Bluetooth device

Comment: and your phone supports that too?